# How struct variable is initialised in this code snippet of I2C controller?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I'm going through the following code snippet from i2c-mpc.c I2C controller.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-mpc.c#L144

```
result = wait_event_timeout(i2c->queue,(i2c->interrupt & CSR_MIF), timeout);
```

I wanted to know how i2c->interrupt is initialised ?

I could see

```
    i2c->interrupt = readb(i2c->base + MPC_I2C_SR);
```

Reading the status register will initialise i2c->interrupt and inside

```
static void mpc_i2c_start(struct mpc_i2c *i2c)
{
 /* Clear arbitration */  
  writeb(0, i2c->base + MPC_I2C_SR);
/* Start with MEN */
   writeccr(i2c, CCR_MEN);
}
```

Zero has been written to status register and i2c->interrupt should have initialised with 0's.

But When I check the dmesg logs and could see i2c->interrupt has initialised to value 0xa2 for write operation.

Can any one point me out how 0xa2 is initialised to i2c->interrupt/how i2c->interrupt is reading the latest update value after write operation ?

Comment: Are you aware that between the execution of mpc_i2c_start and mpc_i2c_isr the controller is likely to change that status register on its own?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the fact that status register value can change between these two routine.